# Ionic Capacitor 404 eror - inappbrowser is not in the npm registry

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

I got an error 404 from running inappbrowser plugin

```
npm install @ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@ionic-enterprise%2finappbrowser - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser@latest' is not in the npm registry.
```

I have also run npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/  but still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

`@ionic-enterprise/inappbrowser` is a private plugin, you can only install it if you are a paid customer or are on trial period. If you are in one of those situations, contact support so they can help you configure your machine to install packages from the private registry.

Answer (score 0):

If your using cordova this would do it:`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser --save`